# a jquery datagrid that supports interactive grouping (and maybe filtering)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datagrid

anybody know of any open source jquery datagrid plugins that support interactive grouping like dragging and dropping a column to the header to group by that column?  I don't see it being possible for jqGrid.  I've seen it in jqxgrid, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at datatables, there is a lot of example on this page, particularly the "Extras" section: [Datatables](http://datatables.net/examples/)

It's a great datagrid, but i'm not sure that the behavior you search for is implemented...